# How to decrease space between two tags within a div

Tags: css, html, spacing

I have a H1 and H2 within a div tag called "welcome". I am trying to decrease the space between the word welcome and the second line of text. I'm struggling to figure this out, but I feel like it will be something simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is an image to show what I'm talking about and my html/css.

[image]

This is my html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Playing with backgrounds</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<a href="index.html">
<div id="logo">
</div>
</a>

<div id="welcome">
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<h2>
To 
<span class="gold"> Promise Land Partners</span></h2>

</div>


<div id="bottom_bar">
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my css

```
body {
    background-image: url(img/dot.png), url(img/background.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position: top left, center center fixed;
    background-size: auto, cover;;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#logo {
    background-image:url(img/PLP.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#logo:hover, #logo:active {
    background-image:url(img/PLP_pushed.png);
}

#bottom_bar {
    background-image:url(img/bottom_bar.jpg);
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 27px;
    width: 100%;
}

#welcome {
    background-image: url(img/welcomepanel.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 70px;
    height: 261px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
}

h1 {
    color:white;
    padding-left: 90px;
    font-size: 6em;
    margin: 0;
}

h2 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 4em;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin: 0;
}

.gold {
    color: #ee9f00;
    font-size: .75em;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `line-height: 0.5em;` for example

Comment: Wow. It's amazing how simple that fix was. Thank you, I'll choose answer when it lets me in 5 mins.

Comment: `line-height` below 1 is not recommended (might cause text to be cut off in some browsers) see my answer below

Comment: @pixelass - That's just FUD unless you can identify such a browser.

Comment: I've seen this issue in Firefox ;). not the latest though. It actually occurred on nested pseudo-elements though.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the `margin` of h1/h2

**Can use a negative margin!**

http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/h1.html

http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/h2.html

http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/h3.html

http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/h4.html

http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/h5.html

http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/h6.html

Comment: The margins are both already set to 0, and there is only a left padding to align within the element.

Comment: You can set margin to negative values... especially the `margin-top` in `h2`

Comment: Also if I change the padding of everything to 0 and then override it with padding-left I still have the same issue.

Comment: Your css is not complete enough to render your image in a JSFiddle, but set a negative `margin-top` on <h2> for example

Comment: I put a -5 margin-top for h2 and nothing happened. I then added a -5 margin-bottom to h1 and still nothing happened. If I change the margin to margin: -5; on h1 then both element move down and if on h2 then h2 moves down, but none of this solves my problem. It only causes more.

Comment: Be sure you include a unit of measurement (UOM). e.g. "px" e.g. `h2{margin-top:-15px;}. UOM is required for any non-zero value :)

Answer (score 1):

Try playing with the `line-height` and/or `margin`

http://jsfiddle.net/Sg6QQ/

```
h1 {
    color:white;
    padding-left: 90px;
    font-size: 6em;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1;
}

h2 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 4em;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin: -0.4em 0 0 0;
    line-height: 1;

}
```

[image]